# Spring integration for large file

Tags: java, etl, batch-processing, large-files, spring-integration

I need to execute ETL operation on large data package using spring integration.
For example, I have huge xml file like:

```
<school>
    <cource name="A">
        <class>
            <name>A1</name>
            <students>20</students>
        </class>
        ...
        <class>
            <name>A35</name>
            <students>19</students>
        </class>
    </cource>
    <cource>
    ...
    </cource>
</school>
```

The result should be 2 cvs files:

First:

```
A1;20
...
A35;35
```

Second:

```
A; 754
..
C; 232
```

That is simple convertion operation and some aggregation function on container. Count of "class" and "cource" records are really huge and I can't parse input data in memory (so i need to iterate by elements),
but i still wan't to use integration patterns for easy modification ETL flow.

Is there any way how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a step with ItemReader and ItemWriter associated with it. Large files are streamed, not read as a whole. So, this should do the magic.

More reading [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html&ei=BKz1UPOHFbK10QWo_4HICQ&usg=AFQjCNGM4VikwDrondxYSP2R-GEU_HlLXw&bvm=bv.41018144,d.d2k). Example [here](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/01/itemreaders-and-itemwriters-in-spring.html#.UPWs8OSsjTo).

Comment: You examples are from Spring Batch, but not Spring integration.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *Spring Integration* to detect the presence of the file and launch a *Spring Batch* job (using the `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` provided in the `spring-batch-integration` project provided in `spring-batch-admin`).